# How are speed run challenges timed?

Tags: diablo-iii

There are several achievements for completing each Act in less than an hour ("No Time to Rest", "Sandskimmer", "Swift Descent", "On the Wings of Angels", "In a Hurry?"). Can I do these runs on normal with a character who has already completed each Act? Do I need to do the runs with a character who has never been to the Act in that difficulty? Does the timer start when I enter the Act the first time, and does it mark an hour from that point, or only count one hour of gameplay time? How do these speed run timers work?

[image: In A Hurry?]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is confirmed. I just completed Act 1 as a level 46 Demon Hunter who is half way through Nightmare and got the achieve.

As a sidenote, I believe this is about the only viable way to do these achieves. I have a run speed buff, and still only had about 3 minutes to spare despite running through mobs and not killing anything unless necessary.